# Java reading key value pair from xml

Tags: java

I am new to java and I want to provide the key which is "aaa" and get the value "bbb" from the below xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <General>
    <add key="aaa" value="bbb"/>
  </General>
</configuration>
```

and this is my code which is not working:

```
           Properties prop = new Properties();
            InputStream is = new FileInputStream("c:\\propFileName.config");
            prop.load(is);
            String result = prop.getProperty("aaa");
```

Please help!

Comment: Do you have control of the structure of the XML? You can use the Properties class to load XML properties files, but they have to be structured differently.

Comment: I dont have control of the structure of the xml since we are using machine.config

Answer (score 3):

Use this for that kind of xml files:

```
try {
    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = builder.parse("E:\\temp\\dist\\filename.config");

    XPathFactory xPathfactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
    XPath xpath = xPathfactory.newXPath();
    XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("//configuration/General/add[@key]");
    NodeList nl = (NodeList) expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);

    for (int c = 0; c < nl.getLength(); c++) {
        Node currentItem = nl.item(c);
        String key = currentItem.getAttributes().getNamedItem("key").getNodeValue();
        String value = currentItem.getAttributes().getNamedItem("value").getNodeValue();
        urlList.put(key, value);
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The file you have placed is xml file and the code you have pasted is reading properties files. 
For reading a xml file you need to use xml parsers[DOM/SAX]. You need to parse element one by one and get the attributes of the element.
Property file is nothing but file with key-value pairs. 
Hope you understood!

Comment: I understand what you mean but i have multiple <add key.. sections, i am not sure how to get the value using dom.

Comment: A SAX parser will emit each tag it finds. If you have multiple `<add> ..</add>` sections they will be emitted as encountered. You should be able to get the value of each key as they are emitted.

Comment: You can google it  parsing xml through java http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=152. you can find lot of links